# CSS 3 animated fixed position sidebar

Tags: css, animation, transition, fixed, sidebar

I was wondering if there is a way to achieve an effect similar to Chris Coyier's: [Scroll/Follow Sidebar](http://css-tricks.com/scrollfollow-sidebar/) using CSS3 animations?

I have a sidebar that scrolls down with the page as the user scrolls (simply using a fixed position div), but I would like to animate that sidebar to sort of bounce down and/or play catch up with the page as the user scrolls down.

Take a look at Chris' [jQuery technique](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ScrollingSidebar/index.php) to see what I'm talking about.

The main thing I would like to know is if it is possible to achieve this effect using **only CSS3** and **no javascript**.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No its not possible to get that effect without JavaScript unless you have some other sort of mechanism that allows you to check how far the user has scrolled, and change CSS properties of elements accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Peeyush. I figured that might be the case seeing as how the javascript measures how far the user scrolls down.

Comment: After watching his [Braindump on Responsive Web Design video](http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/102-braindump-on-responsive-web-design/) I do wonder if there might be another method to achieving the desired result though. At around 12:15 min into the video he shows the search box on CSS Tricks sliding across the screen to reposition itself as he resizes the window. He then goes on to explain how he used CSS3 transition to make it happen.

Comment: While this is more of a responsive media query effect, I do wonder if a similar approach can be taken to the scrolling sidebar? For example, would it be possible to delay the side bar from scrolling with the page and then have it transition down the page easing into place using CSS?

Comment: @juroto , honestly speaking, if there was any way to do this without JavaScript, it would already have been found and would be quiet popular. If you are worried about the people who would visit your site with JavaScript disabled, you don't have to. JavaScript is used to make the users' lives better, and if they have disabled it, its their choice. Use it just to add functionality to your website, and have an alternative for those who don't have JavaScript enabled.